# how to uniquely define a data frame from other data frames, with minimum number of column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and data frames and trying to solve a machine learning problem, but stuck in a problem. I really need to find a way to solve this.

I have 3 binary valued data frames. Each 15*40

Iterating over each data frame, I need to find minimum number of columns for every row, that can uniquely define that row of THAT data frame from other rows of the OTHER data frames.

If a row of a data frame, can be uniquely identified based on Minimum possible number of columns from other data frames. I will look for similar column values in that data frame and remove those. ( generating a rule )

This way, I believe to find the minimum number of columns and its values that can define that data frame's entries from other data frames.

Is there any possible easy way to do it in Python or pandas ?

I am stuck, but so far no success.

*Example:*

**data frame 1:**

```
1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1
```

**data frame 2:**

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

**data frame 3:**

```
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
```

**Expected output is something like this:**

**2 Rules to uniquely define data frame 1:**

- rule 1: first 2 columns with value 1, 0 defines the first and third row
- rule 2: first to columns with value 0, 1 defines the second row

**2 Rules to uniquely define data frame 2:**

- rule 1: first 3 columns with value 1, 1, 1 defines first and second row
- rule 2: first 4 columns with value 1, 1, 1, 1 defines third row

**2 Rules to uniquely define data frame 3:**

- rule 1: first 2 columns with value 0, 0 defines the first and second row
- rule 2: last  2 columns with value 0,1 defines the third row

This is how I want to define rules based on column values to uniquely identify a data frame with the minimum number of columns.

**Pseudo Code I am trying to follow:**

1. for each row *i* in a Data frame
2. Count the occurrence of each column value in other Data frames
3. Order all the columns in row *i* according t their value of
   occurrences
4. Find the minimum number of columns in the ordered column list, that
   uniquely differentiate row *i* from other rows in other Data frames
5. Remove all the rows of that data frame which also satisfies the
   found column and its values.

If the length of that data frame is not 0, continue,

Is there any library or a simple method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this particular problem this way.
It is a working solution. It prints an array of `rules` in the end
The `rules` contains one array for each data frame.
That array consists of a dictionary, stating `{columnName: columnValue}`

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]])

print(df0)
print(df1)
print(df2)

list_dfs = [df0, df1, df2]


def find_rules(list_dfs):
    rules_sets = []
    for idx, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
        trgt_df = df
        other_df = [x for i, x in enumerate(list_dfs) if i != idx]
        other_df = pd.concat(other_df, ignore_index=True)

        def count_occur(value, col_name):
            return other_df[col_name].value_counts().get(value, 0)

        df_dict = []

        for idx, row in trgt_df.iterrows():
            listz = {}
            for col_name in list(trgt_df.columns):
                listz[col_name] = [row[col_name],
                                   count_occur(row[col_name], col_name)]
            df_dict.append(sorted(listz.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))

        rules = []

        def check_for_uniquness(list_of_attr):
            for row in other_df.itertuples(index=False):
                conditions = len(list_of_attr)
                for atr in list_of_attr:
                    if row[atr[0]] == atr[1][0]:
                        conditions = conditions-1
                if conditions == 0:
                    return False
            return True

        def find_col_val(row, val):
            for r in row:
                if r[0] == val:
                    return r[1][0]

        def mark_similar(df_cur, list_of_attr):
            new = []
            for idx, row in enumerate(df_cur):
                combinations = len(list_of_attr)
                for atr in list_of_attr:
                    if find_col_val(row, atr[0]) == atr[1][0]:
                        combinations = combinations-1
                if combinations == 0:
                    new.append(idx)
            return [x for i, x in enumerate(df_cur) if i not in new]

        def return_dictionary(list_of_attr):
            dic = {}
            for idx, el in enumerate(list_of_attr):
                dic[el[0]] = el[1][0]
            return dic

        def possible_combinations(stuff):
            lists = []
            for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
                for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
                    lists.append(list(subset))
            del lists[0]
            return lists

        def X2R(df_dict):
            for elm in df_dict:
                combinations = possible_combinations(list(range(0, len(elm))))
                for combin in combinations:
                    column_combinations = []
                    for i in combin:
                        column_combinations.append(elm[i])
                    if check_for_uniquness(column_combinations):
                        rules.append(return_dictionary(
                            column_combinations))
                        return mark_similar(df_dict, column_combinations)

        while len(df_dict):
            df_dict = X2R(df_dict)

        rules_sets.append(rules)
    return rules_sets


rules = find_rules(list_dfs)
print(rules)
```